# Nginx/Apache to check another webserver status (online / offline)

Tags: apache, nginx, offline, status

OK, so I am using nginx + php fastcgi, I need to show visitors an custom error page saying that the we are experiencing technical problems, how can I do that ?

Should I install nginx on 80 as proxy to another nginx server listening to 8080 and check it's status with HttpHealthcheck Module, or is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You going to need an 3rd party addon to check your backend server, check this: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHealthcheckModule

When the backend is down, nginx answer an 502 error, you can set a custom page for it.

```
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

---

New answer :)

I would use haproxy(http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) for that.

haproxy as your frontend listening on port 80, and nginx+php-fpm as backend

installing HAProxy: (verify your settings and edit the scripts)

```
make TARGET=linux26 CPU=x86_64
cp haproxy /usr/sbin/haproxy
wget http://layer1.rack911.com/haproxy/haproxy-standard.cfg -O /etc/haproxy.cfg
wget http://layer1.rack911.com/haproxy/haproxy.init -O /etc/init.d/haproxy
chmod +x /etc/init.d/haproxy
```

haproxy.cfg (I didn´t include the global/default sessions)

```
frontend webserver-80
        bind <ip>:80
        option forwardfor
        option http-server-close
        default_backend backend-nginx

backend backend-nginx
        #balance roundrobin
        balance source
        option httpchk GET /fpm_ping
        server srv1 <ip>:<port> weight 1 check
        errorfile    503        /etc/errors/503_noserver.txt
```

Check hatop util (http://code.google.com/p/hatop/) or include an stats session to haproxy.cfg so you can check on haproxy status...

```
listen stats :<port>
        balance
        mode http
        stats enable
        stats auth admin:admin
        stats uri /
#       option   httplog
```

Configure php-fpm to respond the ping requests (or change it to other check)

On /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
location /fpm_ping {
    access_log     off;
    allow          <ipaddr/cidr>;
    allow          127.0.0.1;
    deny           all;
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

On /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf include/uncomment

```
ping.path = /fpm_ping
ping.response = pong
```

Comment: I edited my first question because the situation changed a bit, have a look at it now.

Comment: Usefull post man. I have a server that runs varnish / nginx / php-fpm. To monitor the status I just use uptimerobot, which works fine, but it has several downsides. It only checks if the website is up or down. This method brings far more flexibility as you can the state of all your http apps. I will set up a small DotCould app that will monitor the status, and send me back emails when things go down.